# Defaultdict using Django

Tags: python, django

I have a defaultdict like this:

```
{a = [m1,m2,...], b = [m1,m3,...], ... }
```

How could I create a Django model in order to "load" the dictionary on the Admin page? Should I use a ManyToMany relation?

Answer (score 0):

The model that you have needed seems to be the following

```
class MainObjectManager(models.Manager):
    def load(self, data):
        for key, values in data.iteritems():
            main_object = MainObject.objects.create()
            for value in values:
               sub_object = SubObject.objects.get_or_create(main_object=main_object)

class MainObject(models.Model):
    objects = MainObjectManager()

class SubObject(models.Model):
    main_object = models.ForeignKey(MainObject)
```

At this point you can add a command to your django project or, if you prefer, add a init button to admin page of your site to call the load function of main object manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I tested with a simple dictionary and it works correctly! On the site administration page, the objects are called MainObject object and SubObject object (as it should be), is there anyway i could change that?